# How do I make this sentinel control loop work?

Tags: java

It does everything fine. but when it gets to the ends and asks if i want to try again it just terminates the program, i dont get to input y or n

Edit: Sorry, I should have reviewed the preview better before posting, but it seems like i messed up the code when submitting. here is my actual code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class MillionDollarYears2
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String answer = "y";
    double dollars;
    final double interest = 0.05;
    int year = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(answer.equals("y") )
    {
        System.out.println("How many dollars are deposited?");
        dollars = scan.nextDouble();


        while(dollars < 1000000.00)
        {
            dollars = dollars + dollars * interest;
            year = year + 1;
        }
           System.out.println("It took " + year + " years to reach your goal.");

           System.out.println("Would you like to try again? (y or n)");
           answer = scan.nextLine();


    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You aren't entering the y/n answer to the correct variable.
Your relevant snippet (with clarification comments):

```
System.out.println("It took " + year + " years to reach your goal");                                            
answer = scan.nextLine(); // This seems like a mistake

System.out.println("Would you like to try again? (y or n)");
dollars = scan.nextLine(); // This should be saved to answer, which the loop checks against
```

So, after corrections, the end of your while loop should look something like this:

```
System.out.println("It took " + year + " years to reach your goal");                                            

System.out.println("Would you like to try again? (y or n)");
answer = scan.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

It terminates because after this line :

```
 System.out.println("It took " + year + " years to reach your goal");                                            
 answer = scan.nextLine();
```

answer probably holds a value which is not "y" and terminates the while loop.

And after you ask to try again you do :

```
dollars = scan.nextLine();
```

Change `dollars` to `answer` on that line  and remove `answer = scan.nextLine();` two lines before.

Answer (score 0):

change  `scan.nextLine()` to `scan.next()`

working prog :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String answer = "y";
    double dollars;
    final double interest = 0.05;
    int year = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(answer.equals("y") )
    {
        System.out.println("How many dollars are deposited?");
        dollars = scan.nextDouble();


        while(dollars < 1000000.00)
        {
            dollars = dollars + dollars * interest;
            year = year + 1;
        }
           System.out.println("It took " + year + " years to reach your goal.");

           System.out.println("Would you like to try again? (y or n)");
           answer = scan.next();


    }

}
```